# C++ reading multiple lines from stdin

Tags: c++, io, getline, nonblocking

There is a part of a code I wrote in C++:

```
int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << "[" << line << "]\n";
    }   
    return (0);
}
```

Code works properly when it comes to easy examples; it can read multiple lines (single lines in while loop) one by one and display them in terminal:

[image: in terminal]

The problem appears when I try to copy paste two or more lines and print them on the screen; `std::getline()` blocks and is stuck, unable to read the input till the end (I can guess it's already been read and it's stored somewhere in buffer maybe?).

However, when I click enter it displays the input left, line by line, which is completely fine and desired since it - as the name points - reads one line at time.

Is it possible to unblock `std::getline()` somehow so it reads entire block of code?
I hope I explained it well, thanks for helping!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot open your snapshot (contents blocked due to company policy). Can you mention on what system you work?

Comment: It's not possible using only standard C++. You would need to use some OS specific means, which is why everyone is asking which OS you use.

Comment: Please don't post images of text terminals. Text terminals show text. Copy and paste text as text.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine as is. If you are copying text from e.g. a browser window and pasting it to your terminal, it may not get pasted as multiple lines, and you may not get the end-of-line character pasted at the end. You can do precisely nothing about it short of rewriting your OS such that it pastes text the way you want.

Comment: What happens if you type an additional Enter or Return after pasting text? I would expect it to unblock `getline`...

Comment: Did you try to call `cin.clear();` and `cin.sync();` before calling `std::getline()`?

Comment: My macOS is 10.13.4 version (High Sierra)

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen yes I did, doesn't work ;/

Comment: @SergeBallesta of course it unblocks when you add additional Enter, however this is still not a behavior I desire.

Comment: I will try it on my Mac

Comment: sure, let me know whats the result